# restrict opening window B when window A is open

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
public partial class MainMenu : Form
{
    public MainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    windowOne One;
    windowTwo Two;
    private void OneToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (One != null)
        {
            One.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            One.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            One = new windowOne();
            One.MdiParent = this;
            One.FormClosed += (o, ea) => One = null;
            One.Show();
        }
    }

    private void TwoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Two != null)
        {
            TwoWindowState = Two.Normal;
            Two.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            Two = new windowTwo();
            Two.MdiParent = this;
            Two.FormClosed += (o, ea) => Two = null;
            Two.Show();
        }
    }
```

Im beginner in c#,
Im working on window application, i wish when windowOne is open user couldnot open windowTwo, im using above codes to avoid opening windowOne or windowTwo agian..

Comment: no but that fulfill only one requirement, but i wish when window one is open, window could not be opened and that i dont know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could disable either menuitem 1/2 depending on which windows is opened at that moment and then enable it again once u close the window

```
menuItem1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: yes another better approach.. but what do u think willnot it create complex..??

Comment: its the most simple way to disable the menu item depending on which window is selected

Comment: just dont forgot to re-enable the menu item when u close the window

Answer (score 0):

Check both windows before you open then and focus the correct one if one of them is opened. Like this:

```
if (One != null)
{
    One.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    One.Focus();
}
else if (Two != null)
{
    Two.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    Two.Focus();
}
else
{
    // Show the window
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Since these chunks of code are exactly the same it would be better to factor them out into their own method though.

```
public bool IsWindowOpen()
{
    if (One != null)
    {
        One.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        One.Focus();
    }
    else if (Two != null)
    {
        Two.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Two.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You could then use it like so:

```
if (!IsWindowOpen())
{
    // Open window
    Two = new windowTwo();
    Two.MdiParent = this;
    Two.FormClosed += (o, ea) => Two = null;
    Two.Show();
}
```

Comment: great option i never thought about that.. thanx

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept the answer by hitting the tick when you can.

Comment: thanx bro.. quite helping.. but it created another problem ie.. when you opened every menu item in the strip it disable all the menu item in the window.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: i mean when you open one form than closed that, than opened two form, then closed that, after that you are unable to open any of form either one or two..!!

Comment: That means that your `.FormClosed` events aren't firing for some reason.

Comment: no you were rite.. my approach was wrong.. it worked.. actually i was setting formclosed event before One.Show() method.. that created complex.. thanx.. i learn two methods..